# Draw chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm new to flutter and want to draw a chart like image above. I tried many floating libraries on flutter but it didn't work

Comment: Do you want it to expand to show the smaller grids with the button at the top right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.